# WPF set new control position relative within a grid

Tags: wpf, grid, position, controls

This is somewhat a duplicate of other questions so apologies in advance but I haven't been able to make sense of the existing answers (probably because I'm a WPF newb).

I have a grid within a canvas. The grid is added programmatically, not in xaml and is much smaller than the canvas. I want to programmatically add a control (text box) at the position the user clicks on the grid. The application may or may not be full screen and users screen resolutions may differ.

Currently I'm using a mouse down event and getting a point:

```
Dim p As Point = Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid)
```

And then using the point.x and point.y with Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop but this only works when the app is full screen and the screen res is consistent.

I know it's bad form to ask for code but please include a snippet in your answer as I've been wrestling with this for some time & going round in circles. I'm using VB but answers in any language will be welcome. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is not on your code but in your xaml.

```
Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid)
```

should works well.

I think that your Grid is not the same size as your Canvas.
Try something like this:

```
  <DockPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="can">
      <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=can, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=can, Path=ActualWidth}" Background="Red" PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown" />
    </Canvas>
  </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have said that the grid is added programmatically, not in xaml and is much smaller than the canvas. OP updated.

Comment: So don't take the mouse position relative to your grid but to your canvas.
Dim p As Point = Mouse.GetPosition(yourCanvas)

Comment: Thanks. The text box needs to be a child of the grid because later I'm going to export the grid and all user added content like the text box as an image. So Canvas.SetLeft etc won't work. What could I use instead to precisely move the text box within the grid (i.e. not row or column but x / y)? Cheers.

Comment: If you want to add the TextBoxs like childrens of the Grid so why are you trying to set their distance from the Canvas? If you want to put the TextBox as children of your grid you can work on their Margin from the Point taken by Mouse.GetPosition(myGrid)

Comment: You can use the Margin of your TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

`Grid` arranges its children basically mostly on the child's `Margin` property.
So do this `OnClick` of your grid:

```
// dont forget to add an event handler on creating the grid
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.MouseDown += myGrid_MouseDown;

private void myGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouserEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(myGrid);        

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Margin = new Thickness(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0);
    tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; // cuz we set margin on Top and Left sides..

    myGrid.Children.Add(tb);
}
```

Hope it helps :)